# Updated OMD and Check_MK Agent returns Null

Tags: monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I updated OMD to the current version using the following:

```
omd update <site>
```

Everything appears to update fine, but now my servers with the check_mk agent installed show (null) and I do not have current data. Here is a weird bit: it will inventory the services just fine, so the agent is working on the server to some extent. I have also attempted:

```
check_mk -II
check_mk -R
```

But that, too, did not work. If I spin up a new site and add one of the servers, it inventories fine, so I find it odd that an existing site is having issues getting updated information. I am hoping somebody can help me with this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

does this also happen if you do

cmk -v server_host_name

or will that correctly return a status?
If it works fine, there's two routes to look into:

1. Precompiling of checks is broken
   cmk -R does do that, but maybe it actually failed. I'd try
   cmk --debug -R (most of cases, this should be the issue) and even if that came out OK, I'd also delete the precompiled checks from var/check_mk/precompiled
2. A non-working nagios core (omd status), or issue with the config of it.
   (i.e. if you'd use livecheck or mod_gearman and this stopped working, or if the check result files aren't read any more...)

In any case, check the Nagios logfiles for this and the --debug -v flag to check_mk will also help you.

Comment: Hi Florian. Thanks for the reply. I will give this a shot tomorrow at the office and report back.